# C-lightning lightningd crashing

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning

To run a lightning node I followed the instructions here: https://medium.com/@dougvk/run-your-own-mainnet-lightning-node-2d2eab628a8b except that I downloaded and installed bitcoind and lightningd from source and not in a docker. I can fund my on-chain wallet, connect to peers but when I try to open a channel the daemon crashes, with the following message in crash.log:

```
+61107.734361005 lightningd(30005):BROKEN: wallet_channel_save: UPDATE channels SET  fundingkey_remote=?,  revocation_basepoint_remote=?,  payment_basepoint_remote=?,  htlc_basepoint_remote=?,  delayed_payment_basepoint_remote=?,  per_commit_remote=?,  old_per_commit_remote=?,  local_feerate_per_kw=?,  remote_feerate_per_kw=?,  channel_config_remote=? WHERE id=?: no such column: local_feerate_per_kw
+61108.166336903 lightningd(30005):BROKEN: FATAL SIGNAL 6 RECEIVED
```

What does local feerate per kw mean? To set the tx fee of bitcoind I followed the instruction from the blog post:
bitcoin-cli settxfee 0.0004

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the database schema update was not successful. Meaning the database is not in a known good state. I'd suggest closing any open channels, withdrawing all funds from this node into an external wallet, moving the database (or the entire `.lightning` directory) and then restarting the client to create a fresh database.

This version is also really old, so the issue has most likely been addressed in the meantime.